# connection reset by peer，how long linux kernel keep a idle connection

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I have a daemon script, it will connect beanstalkd. This script will run 3 hours. it will put one job with a tcp connection, however, after 1.5 hours ,when put the second job with this connection. the socket will receive a error "connection reset by peer".
 Beanstalk will not close a connection.So I want to know if the Linux kernel will automatically close the idle connection？ And if yes, how long the linux kernel will keep the idle connection？

Answer (score 2):

Yes linux-kernel will reset the idle connection depending upon your ssh-configuration.
You must use option BatchMode=yes and also set ServerAliveInterval in your ssh-config file(path is /home//.ssh/config) default is 300 in case of BatchMode yes.
ServerAliveInterval sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, it will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server. Also put TCPKeepAlive=yes option in your ssh-config file.
 Kernel will use these configurations to detect the tcp connection status. However, it is useful in long running scripts.